# When we should use Java Extension Class Loader?

Tags: java, class, jakarta-ee, classloader

I have clear understanding on Bootstarp and Application class loader but do know know when we should use extension class loader as we already have Application Claa Loader for the same.
Explanation with real time example would be highly appreciated..

Comment: Since the whole extension stuff is going to die with Java 9, don’t waste time dealing with it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually extension class loader is always used by JVM. Run this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent());
}
```

and you will see that Application class loader parent is extension class loader. It simply adds all jars in jre\lib\ext to JVM class search path. Java holds platform-specific jars there

Comment: Thanks For your comments..
Can you tell me any real scenario where i can use Extension Class Loader Facility..